# Response is not coming after sending notification using Webpush in C#

Tags: c#, web, push-notification, asp.net-web-api2, web-push

I am using Webpush library to send webpush notification to web app,i have developed API for sending push notificaton there is method in library called **SendNotification** after hitting API,there is no response is coming.[ [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuwpP.png][1]

```
public HttpResponseMessage sendNotification(Notification notify)
    {
        try
        {
            var subscription = new PushSubscription(notify.endPoint, notify.p256dh, notify.auth);
            if (subscription != null)
            {
                client.SendNotification(subscription, "clarifide notification received");
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, notify);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal Server Error");
            }
        }
        catch (WebPushException e)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Either the URL is bad,the server isn't running, or you do not have a route to the server.

Comment: url is right m dam sure about that & server is also running, & also https certificate is already installed. please help me anyone

Comment: Can you Open a Browser and paste the URL into the address and wee what the fiddler response is?

Comment: You can see here the fiddler response https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuwpP.png][1]

Comment: That fiddler response is from your application.  I want to see the response from an IE doing it manually.

Comment: It's post request so it can't be called from web browser

Comment: The URL in the png posted can still be put into an IE.  It can give some good debug info to help troubleshoot issue.  Just include everything starting with  https://